# Where to locate accepted values for an attribute [PHP preffered but can be considered for all languages]

Tags: php, class, dependencies, entities

I have an entity, let's say "customer" and this entity has 3 possible status: **active**, **inactive** and **deleted**.

This 3 status handles 3 labels: **Active**, **Inactive** and **Deleted** and they are used in the form, in the detail and maybe in a list so I we have a common array:

```
array(
   'active' => 'Active',
   'inactive' => 'Inactive',
   'deleted' => 'Deleted
);
```

What I normally do is to handle this in a method called **getAcceptedStatus** that returns this values but then I figured out that I had to make something like this:

```
$acceptedStatus = $customer->getAcceptedStatus();
echo $acceptedStatus[$customer->getStatus()];
```

And I do not find it good enough. How do you (would you) handle it? Should I create a method that return directly the label?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the `status` an entity in its own right?

This way you can assign the customers status property an object instance rather then messing around with strings.

```
abstract class Status 
{
  protected $id;

  protected $name;

  public function getId();

  public function setId($id);

  public function getName();

  public function setName($name);

}

class CustomerStatus extends Status
{
 protected $label;


 public function getLabel()
 {
   return $this->label;
 }

 public function setLabel($label);

}
```

Then type hint in the customer class:

```
class Customer {
  // ...
  public function getStatus() {
    return $this->status;
  }

  public function setStatus(CustomerStatus $status) {
   $this->status = $status;
  }

  // ...
}
```